# Why add xliff:g tag to <item><xliff:g id="id">ime</xliff:g></item>?

Tags: android

I am studying the statusbar, I found those code in the config.xml:

```
<!-- Do not translate. Defines the slots for the right-hand side icons.  That is to say, the
         icons in the status bar that are not notifications. -->
    <string-array name="config_statusBarIcons">
       <item><xliff:g id="id">ime</xliff:g></item>
       <item><xliff:g id="id">sync_failing</xliff:g></item>
      ......

    </string-array>
```

Why add xliff:g tag to them? I know xliff is "XML Localisation Interchange File Format".But there is nothing to format in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a convention to always use xliff, even if it is not required - simply to keep things clean. AFAIK, xliff is not required if there is nothing to do with localizers.